# how to access ajax response which is a array of structures?

Tags: jquery

```
var request = jQuery.ajax({
    url: "calculation.cfm",
    type: "post",
    traditional : true,
    contentType: 'application/json',   
    data:JSON.stringify(arrayA),
    success: function(e){
        alert(e[0].fee);
        return false;
   }
});
```

calculation.cfm

#SerializeJSON(result)#;

variable "result"is an array of structures.

so response is like this
[{"FEE":387500,"CLIENT":1125000.0},{"FEE":950000,"CLIENT":9.375E7}];

Actually alert is undefined. How to access each value?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are recieving an Object from your server (I don't know because you don't use `dataType` property in your ajax call). You should access to it as: `key => value`.

**Example**

```
success: function(data){
    alert("id: " + data.clientId + ", name: " + data.clientName);
}
```

You don't need to `return false` to end a function in JavaScript. Also, if you can't get it in that way, leave a comment to solve your problem and/or show an example of your response data.

(i.e.) **JSON:** `{"clientId": "1", "clientName": "MyName"}`